# UICollectionView Custom layout reloading issue in Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

This is refrence link:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

I have implemented load more in `UICollectionView` at last cell , the data is getting downloaded, after download complete i want to reload collection

```
collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
self.collectionView.reloadData()

let concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
dispatch_async(concurrentQueue) {
            DataManager.sharedInstance.homeRequest(Dictionary: params, onSuccess: { (dict) in
                self.downloadPageIndex +=  1
                let response = HomeObject(dictionary: dict)

                for (_,e) in (response.dataDict?.enumerate())!{
                    self.dataArray.append(e)
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()

                }
                self.activityIndicatorCell.stopAnimating()

                }, onError: { (error) in
                    self.activityIndicatorCell.stopAnimating()

            })
```

like this  collectionview reloadata

Can any one help me out?

Comment: And what's wrong with these lines? What's your issue?

Comment: Can you show the load more? What is happening when you receive the data?

Comment: Collectionview is not reloading ....

Comment: Show more code, where are You calling those lines?

Comment: You probably fetching the data on a background thread. UI updates however have to happen on the main thread. Try calling the reload method on the main thread. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am calling on Main thread @riik

Answer (score 8):

Ran into your question and am currently facing the same problem, after some digging i figured it out!

The problem is within the `PintrestLayout` file

Inside you will find code like (**PROBLEM**) :

`guard cache.isEmpty == true, let collectionView = collectionView else {
return
}`

Basically, if the attributes that you are applying to the CollectionView are empty (they are at the start), apply the PintrestLayout to it, and thats perfect! **BUT** If you are reloading the data and adding to the collectionView, you need to apply the layout again, but the cache isnt empty when you try to apply the layout to the collectionView again, thus it returns and doesn't work at all...

**SOLUTION** :

replace that code with :

```
guard cache.isEmpty == true || cache.isEmpty == false, let collectionView = collectionView else {
        return
    }
```

Now you are saying "i dont care if its empty or not, just apply the damn layout to my collectionView"

And Done! Now `reloadData()` will update how many cells you got...

This is pretty expensive though, if you wanna make it faster, and trim some memory etc... Then look into invalidateFlowLayout Documentation.

Comment: That goes for anyone in the future facing this problem too!

Comment: this doesn't make any sense, if true or false?

Comment: @JimTierney your right. Looking back at it, all you need is the guard to check if its nil thats all. The result of the boolean doesnt matter!

Comment: Thank you so much you saved me