# UICollectionView infinitive Scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I searched this topic but can't find any solution on my problem.This is my loadData function can get datas from JSON object

```
 @IBOutlet weak var collectionVitrin: UICollectionView!

 var vitrinDecodePost = [VitrinDecode]() // Decodable

 func loadDatas(limit : Int) {

    guard let url = URL(string: "my Url") else { return }
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let paramString = "limit=\(limit)"
    request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in
            guard let _:NSData = data as NSData? , let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {

                print("Mistake")
                return
            }

            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {

                let abc = try JSONDecoder().decode([VitrinDecode].self, from: data)
                self.vitrinDecodePost = abc

                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    self.collectionVitrin.reloadData()
                }

            } catch { print(error)}

    }
    task.resume()
}
```

I run this function in my ViewDidLoad :

```
var deger : Int = 10

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadData(limit: deger)
}
```

When scroll is end I want to add more data so I added willDisplay function

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.vitrinDecodePost.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let lastindex = self.vitrinDecodePost.count - 1
    if indexPath.row == lastindex{

        loadDatas(limit: 20)
        self.collectionVitrin.reloadData() 


    }

}
```

When page loaded 10 items display in my cells but when I reach end of page (last index) collectionview don't display anything . It must be show 20 items in my collectionview cells. What did I forget?

Comment: set a breakpoint inside the do loop and see it the response is what you expected.

Comment: You are setting "self.vitrinDecodePost = abc" everytime. You should append the items.

Comment: please help us with more code. can you please post all the delegates that your class is confirming to ? more specifically for `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: Not worked @cekisakurek .

Comment: fetchDatas will be loaddatas my mistake I updated @meggar

Comment: When I send 20 as a limit my 20 items coming from JSON there is no mistake about it @meggar

Comment: are you sure that the function call `loadDatas(limit: 20)` is being made? can you add an `print(" ....")` statement inside if block ?

Comment: Yes When scroll is end if statement running @AppleCiderGuy

Comment: I think mistake is about reloading data because `loadDatas(limit: 20)` run and return 20 items

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik btw, this logic doesn't makes much sense to me. If you keep reloading your data being on index 10, and if you keep calling `self.collectionVitrin.reloadData()` immidiately after the async API call, you would keep refreshing your table. try removing `self.collectionVitrin.reloadData()` from below `loadDatas(limit: 20)`

Comment: I tried and run loadDatas(limit: 20) but didn't reload data same 10 items is disappear but 20 items coming from json but don't reload @AppleCiderGuy

Comment: And also after `loadDatas(limit: 20)`  when I print `self.vitrinDecodePost.count` return `20` There is no issues about it

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `self.collectionVitrin.reloadData()` called just after `LoadDatas(limit: 20)` in your `willDisplay` function.

But If I can give you an advice to implement infinite scroll on a collectionview I would change a few thing.

First of all I would advise you to change you api call.
You should keep the limit for the number of element sent back from each api call but also implement an offset variable. This is much more efficient.

In your case your second api call is just asking for the same objects again with a bigger limit in the request. Your are basically asking for the same data each time.
Adding an offset enables you to only request new data each time. This offset should be the amount of data you already have.

Secondly you should try and add a fail safe mechanism when you reach the end of your data or when you are already requesting data. Otherwise you will end up looping on calls if you reach the bottom of your collection view. Here is how I would implement the infinite loading based on your code

```
 @IBOutlet weak var collectionVitrin: UICollectionView!
 var limitPerCall: Int = 10
 var isLoadindNewData = false
 var shouldLoadMoreData = true

 var vitrinDecodePost = [VitrinDecode]() // Decodable

 func loadDatas(limit : Int, offset: Int) {

     guard let url = URL(string: "my Url") else { return }
     let session = URLSession.shared
     let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
     request.httpMethod = "POST"
     let parameters = ["limit": "\(limit)", "offset": "\(offset)"] as Dictionary<String, String>
     guard let httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else { return }
     request.httpBody = httpBody

     let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { [weak self]
         (data, response, error) in
         guard let strongSelf = self, let _:NSData = data as NSData? , let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {

            print("Mistake")
            return
        }

       /// No More data to gather stop making api calls
        guard let data = data else { 
           strongSelf.shouldLoadMoreData = false
           return 
        }
        do {

            let abc = try JSONDecoder().decode([VitrinDecode].self, from: data)
            strongSelf.vitrinDecodePost.append(contentsOf: abc)

            //// Reload the new data and and indicates that api call can be 
            made again
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                strongSelf.isLoadingNewData = false
                strongSelf.collectionVitrin.reloadData()
            }

        } catch { print(error)}

}
task.resume()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection 
    section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.vitrinDecodePost.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: 
    UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let lastindex = self.vitrinDecodePost.count - 1
    if indexPath.row == lastindex && !isLoadindNewData && shouldLoadMoreData {
        /// Forbids multiple api calls to happen at the same time
        isLoadindNewData = true
        loadDatas(limit: limitPerCall, offset: vitrinDecodePost.count)
    }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Best

Comment: I tried but same issue. Json object coming but Swift don't reload table again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744668/uicollectionview-custom-layout-reloading-issue-in-swift Its about Pinterest layout I saw issues . Thanks to help me